# Notebook wont boot after adding new ram

Tags: memory

I have a Gateway Notebook NV55C, it has two memory modules Kingston ACR256X64D3S1333C9, 2GB DDR3-1333 each (4GB). I works just fine.

I wanted to upgrade to 8GB, so I bought two kingston kvr13s9s8/4 4GB DDR3-1333 each.

Then, when I try to boot my notebook with this new memories, it simply wont boot at all. It powers the machine but it does not show anything. I cant even get into bios of course.

So, I try installing only one memory module. It appears to boot OK but the OS cant starts (Ubuntu or Windows), it just reboots.

If I install my old memomries, the notebook works perfectly.

What is suppose to be wrong here? As far as I know the memory specs should work according to my notebook specs.

Comment: memory is incompatible, give Kingston a call to verify.

Comment: Ok so I called kingston and yes, memory is incompatible. I just dont understand exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to speed factor. Exchange them for 1066 MHz or PC3-8500. It will work perfectly. 1333 MHz on maximum ram will not work usually if the actual running speed for the Gateway NV55C is 1066 MHz.

If you want to check out a new ram or for Gateway Notebook NV55C compatible RAM memory, refer this: http://www.memorystock.com/orderitem.asp?it=840ms-840&MnfId=&MdlId=8111021206